# Ошибка линковки С проект на VS2019

Tags: c++, c

Есть такая ошибка линковки проекта VS2019 (проект изначально сделан на С под компилятор gcc):

Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _Effect_Blood    TOMBRAID    I:\TOMBRAID\teeth_trap.obj  1

Функция Effect_Blood() находится в файле blood.h и blood.c, причем оба файла включены в проект (есть в солюшене).

Почему возникает эта ошибка?
Заранее спасибо.